# Is it possible to change the class of an element if the class of another elements equals to sth?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to remove/add the `classList` of some element if the `classList` of another element is equal to "sth". But there is a little problem that it only runs the command once, I mean the condition doesn't check the `classList` of the first element every second so it runs it without any problem. If the *if* is true then it runs the *if condition* and then it won't check *else if* and so reverse.

Here is my code:

```js
const dToggle = () => {
  const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
  
  firstElm.classList.toggle('red-border');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', dToggle);

const orangeOrRed = () => {
    const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
    const secondElm = document.querySelector('.secondElm');

    firstElm.classList === 'red-border' ? secondElm.classList.add('red') : secondElm.classList.add('orange');
    
    // if (firstElm.classList === 'red-border') {
    //        secondElm.classList.remove('orange');
    //        secondElm.classList.add('red');
    // } else if (firstElm.classList === 'orange-border' {
    //        secondElm.classList.remove('red');
    //        secondElm.classList.add('orange');
    // };
};

// Maybe the exact problem is right here.
window.addEventListener('load', orangeOrRed);

console.log(document.querySelector('.secondElm').classList.value);
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}

.firstElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 
.orange-border {
  border: orange 3px solid;
}
 
.red-border {
  border: red 3px solid;
}
 
.secondElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click here.</button>
<p>It should run the conditional statement whenever I click on the button to apply the border.</p>
<p> First Elm Border Color (MUST BE) Second Elm Background Color</p>
<div class='firstElm orange-border'></div>
<div class='secondElm'></div>
<p style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Remember that I only want to do this with(conditioal statements), It's possible either with classList.toggle() but I don't want to.</p>
```

Comment: It is still a little difficult to understand.  `there is a little problem that it only runs the command once, I mean the condition doesn't check the classList of the first element every second so it runs it without any problem.` Maybe you can rephrase this. Also is your if else code relevant or conditional operator more relevant to the code?

Comment: Worth pointing out that both your button event listener has no if condition and will always run the same. and your window load listener will always run once. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: If you want your code to run when the class changes, call the function in your code where you change the class. Or use a `MutationObserver`, knowing that it could slow down your site. Also `classList` is a `DOMTokenList`, not a string, so `firstElm.classList` will never be equal to `'red-border'`. You should use `classList.contains('red-border')`

Comment: What do you mean by ``If you want your code to run when the class changes, call the function in your code where you change the class.``? @HereticMonkey

Comment: I mean, if you have code that changes the `classList` of those elements, call `orangeOrRed()` in that function.

Comment: That's what I did. Called the conditional statement in that function. Otherwise, I couldn't get your purpose. Maybe you can write the code. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have three problems:

#### 1. Checking for the wrong condition

classList is a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) that has a [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method which returns true if the element has the desired className or vice versa

#### 2. Adding the same className multiple times without removing the old one

you need to remove the `orange` className if you want to add the `red` className and vice versa

#### 3. The `orangeOrRed` function runs only once

The `orangeOrRed` function runs only once on window's load event

You need to add the same event listener to the button's click event

```js
const dToggle = () => {
  const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
  firstElm.classList.toggle('red-border');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', dToggle);

const orangeOrRed = () => {
    const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
    const secondElm = document.querySelector('.secondElm');

    if (firstElm.classList.contains('red-border')) {
            secondElm.classList.remove('orange');
            secondElm.classList.add('red');
    } else if (firstElm.classList.contains('orange-border')) {
            secondElm.classList.remove('red');
            secondElm.classList.add('orange');
    };
};

// You're right, the exact problem is right here.
window.addEventListener('load', orangeOrRed);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', orangeOrRed);

console.log(document.querySelector('.secondElm').classList.value);
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}

.firstElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 
.orange-border {
  border: orange 3px solid;
}
 
.red-border {
  border: red 3px solid;
}
 
.secondElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click here.</button>
<p>It should run the conditional statement whenever I click on the button to apply the border.</p>
<p> First Elm Border Color (MUST BE) Second Elm Background Color</p>
<div class='firstElm orange-border'></div>
<div class='secondElm'></div>
<p style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Remember that I only want to do this with(conditioal statements), It's possible either with classList.toggle() but I don't want to.</p>
```

Achieving the same results using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

It's useful when you have no toggle button or when you're not in control of when the class name of the element changes.

```js
const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
const secondElm = document.querySelector('.secondElm');

const orangeOrRed = () => {
    if (firstElm.classList.contains('red-border')) {
            secondElm.classList.remove('orange');
            secondElm.classList.add('red');
    } else if (firstElm.classList.contains('orange-border')) {
            secondElm.classList.remove('red');
            secondElm.classList.add('orange');
    };
}

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationsList) => {  
  // check to see if the changed attribute that caused the mutationObserver callback to be called is the class attribute and run the desired code
  if (mutationsList[0].attributeName === 'class') orangeOrRed();
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
// Here the MutationObserver will call the specified callback just if attributes of the target node have changed
const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false };

// Start observing the target node (firstElm) for configured mutations
observer.observe(firstElm, config);

const dToggle = () => {
  firstElm.classList.toggle('red-border');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', dToggle);

// You're right, the exact problem is right here.
window.addEventListener('load', orangeOrRed);
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}

.firstElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 
.orange-border {
  border: orange 3px solid;
}
 
.red-border {
  border: red 3px solid;
}
 
.secondElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click here.</button>
<div class='firstElm orange-border'></div>
<div class='secondElm'></div>
<p style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Remember that I only want to do this with(conditioal statements), It's possible either with classList.toggle() but I don't want to.</p>
```

Comment: This was the only thing it needed to work finely. ``document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', orangeOrRed);`` merci ;)
But what if I don't have any buttons to use ``addEventListener`` I mean you wouldn't be able to click on sth to run the func, then what?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.
If you had no button to click on, then you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I will post an answer using the `MutationObserver API` tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You've misinterpreted what the problem is here; it's not that the conditional isn't running, it's that it's checking the wrong thing.

You're looking to see if a DOM element's `classList === 'orange-border'` but this will never be true; classList isn't a simple string. What you want is to see if the classList *includes* orange-border.

```js
const dToggle = () => {
  const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');

  firstElm.classList.toggle('red-border');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', dToggle);

const orangeOrRed = () => {
    const firstElm = document.querySelector('.firstElm');
    const secondElm = document.querySelector('.secondElm');

    // I'm not sure why you have both this ternary and the similar if:else below, but I've fixed both to at least be checking the classList correctly:
    firstElm.classList.contains('red-border') ? secondElm.classList.add('red') : secondElm.classList.add('orange');


    if (firstElm.classList.contains('red-border')) {
      secondElm.classList.remove('orange');
      secondElm.classList.add('red');
    } else if (firstElm.classList.contains('orange-border')) {
        secondElm.classList.remove('red');
        secondElm.classList.add('orange');
      };
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', orangeOrRed);

console.log(document.querySelector('.secondElm').classList.value);
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}

.firstElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.orange-border {
  border: orange 3px solid;
}

.red-border {
  border: red 3px solid;
}

.secondElm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click here.</button>
<p>It should run the conditional statement whenever I click on the button to apply the border.</p>
<p> First Elm Border Color (MUST BE) Second Elm Background Color</p>
<div class='firstElm orange-border'></div>
<div class='secondElm'></div>
<p style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Remember that I only want to do this with(conditioal statements), It's possible either with classList.toggle() but I don't want to.</p>
```